# Как разбить огромное число в массиве на несколько частей?

Tags: javascript

Дано:

`var arr = [11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111];`

Необходимо получить:

`[1111111111,1111111111,1111111111,1111111111,1111111111]`

Answer (score 1):

Для числа:

```js
let number = BigInt(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111);
number = number + '';

const step = 10;
const n_len  = number.length;
const array_numbers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < n_len; i += step) {
  array_numbers.push(number.slice(i,i+step));
}

console.log(array_numbers);
```

Для строки:

```js
const number = '11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111';

const step = 10;
const n_len  = number.length;
const array_numbers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < n_len; i += step) {
  array_numbers.push(number.slice(i,i+step));
}

console.log(array_numbers);
```